# In-line assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

For the below code, if i want to convert the for loop to in-line assembly, how would it be done?
(Pardon the weird code, i just made it up.)

1) This is for the x86, using visual studio

2) This is a "how to use in line assembly" question, not a "how to optimize this code" question

3) Any other example will be fine. I will think of some better example code in abit.

OK i hope this is a better example:

```
int doSomething(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double d;
    for(int i=100;i<200;i++)
    {
        d = a*a + b*b + c*c;
        if(d>i)
            return (i-99);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for doing this ? A decent compiler will probably do a much better job than a noob assembly programmer ever can. And what CPU are you targetting ?

Comment: Also note that your code has a redundant expression inside the loop - the second line is pointless as b is immediately replaced by c. You might want to fix your code before trying to optimise it.

Comment: And another thing - the loop itself is redundant as all the expressions inside it are loop-invariant. You haven't really thought this through, have you ?

Comment: On what architecture? What compiler? Some things which are easy to do in GCC become more fickle in other compilers.

Comment: You should make it clear whether you are asking this out of simple curiosity, or whether you actually think you need to use assembly language for something like this.

Comment: @ theatrus - I am using VS on the x86.
@ Paul - This code is not meant to do anything, I want to learn how to use in line assembly. The point is to understand the syntax, not to optimize the code. I probably should have come up with a better example though

Comment: If you want a reasonable example use a function that takes parameters and manipulates them.

Comment: Why are people down-voting this perfectly fine question?

Comment: @Heath: you may not have seen the question in its original form - it has been edited and improved slightly now.

Comment: @aCuria: you've improved the question a little now, but the function is still not a very good example and has many of the same problems as the original. Why not post a real function that you want to convert to assembly ?

Comment: If you want to start programming in assembly using Visual Studio, I recommend NOT using inline assembly, as it is not supported in 64 bit any longer. In 64 bit you create the assembly functions in an seperate asm file and link them to your application. The same can be done with 32 bit applications, so that is the way I would recommend to go as it enables you to switch the compilation target on the fly. Follow the link to see how it is done:  http://www.sciencezero.org/index.php?title=How_to_write_x64_assembly_functions_in_Visual_C%2B%2B

Comment: Mind you 64 bit assembly does not quite work the same way as 32 bit assembly. It does use the fastcall calling convention and differently sized registers (obviously). So the actual functions need to be declared differently in your assembly file. How this is done is too much info for a comment or even an SO answer tho. Also the process of researching exactly how this is done will teach a lot about what happens behind the curtains - to me it did anyway :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably start out something like this incomplete and somewhat inefficient example. Should demonstrate the syntax, though.

```
double doSomething(void) {
    double a=1,b=2,c=3;
    __asm {
        mov ecx,10
loop:
        fld a // a
        fmul st(0),st(0) // aa
        fld b // b aa
        fmul st(0),st(0) // bb aa
        fsubp // aa-bb
        fstp c // c = a*a-b*b

        // and so on

        dec ecx
        jnz loop
    }
    return a+b+c;
}
```

Using SSE instructions would be another option.

The VC++ inline assembler is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx

The Intel processor reference manuals are here: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Answer (score 3):

Here's an [Inline Assembly tutorial](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) and another [Using Inline Assembly in C/C++ tutorial on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/edujini_inline_asm.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Totally dependent upon compiler and architecture.  You'll need to scour the web for information on inline asm for your compiler and then learn the asm op codes for your architecture (in the correct asm dialect -- compiler dependent).

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise this without resorting to assembler:

```
double doSomething(void)
{
    double a = 1.0, b = 2.0, c = 3.0;
    c = a * a - b * b;
    b = c;
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Or if you turn up the optimisation level:

```
double doSomething(void)
{
    return -5.0;
}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote ? With no comment ? It's a perfectly valid answer to the question (as originally posed).

Comment: If someone wanted to learn how to calculate the value of pi to 5 decimal places, it wouldn't be overly helpful to answer "3.14159" unless they could come back to you for a new answer when they decided they wanted 10 or 100 decimal places. Teach a man to fish...

Comment: @Dinah: well there actually is a serious point here, which is often overlooked, and that is that you need to optimise at a high level before resorting to micro-optimisations such as hand-coded assembler (which should always be a last resort). Also, the question as originally posed lacked detail and context, so it wasn't clear what the asker *really* was trying to do. The trigger-happy down-voters among us so often miss such subtle points.

Comment: I have now looked at the original post and still disagree that this is a helpful answer. (For the record though it wasn't me who downvoted you)

Comment: @Dinah: OK - let's agree to differ then - I'll probably delete this answer shortly as it no longer applies to the question in its present form.

Answer (score 1):

No real point learning inline assembly. Its not supported for x64 (with Visual Studio, that is). Whether you are using x64 now or not using it, at some point you will be and inline will be history.

Better learn how to use MASM instead, where what you learn for x86 will be still useful for x64.

Comment: I've seen a lot of "what's the point" arguments online lately. I applaud you putting forth a better way to do things in case the OP wasn't aware of them, but regarding "what's the point" -- who cares what the "point" is? I didn't even begin programming with a "point" in mind. I did it because it was fun and interesting. Most of my hobby programs don't have a "point" either, they're just something I want to do. I created an esoteric programming language once that did very little. What was the point? Because I wanted to.

Comment: Whilst inline assembly is not supported for 64 bit in Visual Studio, assembly itself is. Basically you declare the function in C++, then code the asm function in an seperate asm file and link them when building the application. Whilst this is not "inline" per sé, it is just another way of doing the same thing. And it does matter - for example when coding 32 bit and 64 bit versions of a VST plugin (or converting a 32 bit VST plugin to 64 bit). Here a link to see how this works: http://www.sciencezero.org/index.php?title=How_to_write_x64_assembly_functions_in_Visual_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to have the compiler print the assembly language for a function.  Use this as a baseline for inline assembly.

In general, inline assembly should be avoided as it is platform specific, especially processor specific.  A better solution is to put the function into a separate file.  Create a C language version and an assembly language version.  In your build process, choose between the different files.  This will allow you to have different assembly language versions for different platforms and processors with minimal side-effects to the rest of your program (which is very important).